# There is no place or There is no place in the world

Tags: idioms, negation, existentials

Given the sentence:

> New restaurants are appearing all over the place.

If I change this sentence using "There is no" structure, the possible answers are:

> 1.There is no place where new restaurants are not 
>   appearing.
>
> 2.There is no place *in the world* where new restaurants are not appearing.

According to question, I am not sure whether my answer needs to add "in the world" after *place* or not.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic phrase you are using

> all over the place

is synonymous with

> all around me
>   all around this area
>   everywhere

however, the extent is dependent on context.

> The kids' toys are *all over the place*. *(standing in a room)*
>   *toys are everywhere in this room*
>
> It's a blizzard! Snow is just falling *all over the place*! *(standing outside)*
>   *snow is falling everywhere around me (within my visible area)*
>
> New restaurants are appearing *all over the place*. *(standing on a street corner)*
>   *new restaurants are opening all over town*
>
> Global warming will cause weather disruptions *all over the place*.
>   *weather disruptions throughout the world*

Usually, if one wants to refer to the *entire world* one might use

> New restaurants are appearing *everywhere*.
>   Global warming will cause weather disruptions *everywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these sentences are perfectly natural, but they do mean different things.  Because "place" is inherently ambiguous, without further context it's assumed to mean the general locale of what was previously discussed:

> "Can you believe what just happened in the US election?" "Yes, I can't stand this place anymore.

"this place" = "The United States"

> "Ugh the apartment is a mess! Could you please clean this place up?"

"this place" = "this apartment"

> There's no place like home

"place" = "the world"

Without any context, as in your example ("New restaurants are appearing all over the place") we assume you mean your local *neighborhood* or, at most, your *city*.  This doesn't change if you invert it to "There is no place where ... is not happening."  It's still the same *place*.

However if you add more information to the sentence it becomes clear what *place* you are talking about.

> There is no place in that city where you can get a good hamburger
>
> In Japan, there are shrines and temples all over the place.
>
> There is no place in the world like Paris.